# Animate time series data from .csv file using Geometry nodes

Tags: python, animation, geometry-nodes

Using geometry nodes I want to animate time-series data stored inside a .csv file. In animation nodes, something like this is [possible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aRjInmibSw) as python API calls can be directly evaluated.

As there is currently no scripting node for geometry nodes I am looking for a workaround. My first idea was to store the data in an attribute, which can be accessed using geometry nodes. However, I do not know how to animate or change the attribute over time.

Comment: I don’t know what kind of data you have because you provided no information at all about it, but let me assume you have time + coordinate, so you could write that information via animation nodes to a cube and use this cube‘s animated data (coordinates +time) in geometry nodes. Hint: a small example how your csv looks like would help. A concrete example what you want to make would help. The more concrete your question is, the better will be the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Application Handlers to update values on frame change

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html

```
import bpy


def my_handler(scene):
    print("Frame Change", scene.frame_current)
    # update attributes here


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```